# How to fetch the data from the database by using this demo?

Tags: android, database, sqlite, database-design, android-ndk

I am using [this example](http://www.reigndesign.com/blog/using-your-own-sqlite-database-in-android-applications/) to create the database in to amy android app.

But here it is not given that how to fetch the data from the database.

My fields are like:

_id

name

address

type

now i want to show the all available name from the database.

I know that i have to use Select query. but where i have to use it that i dont know. So please can anybudy help e for that.

Thanks.

Comment: just have to post comment about answers ... you shouldn't do this (loading data to array and then using ArrayAdapter<>) ... if you wana show data stored in sqlite db on android using listview you should use SimpleCursorAdapter instead ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Write your method in `DataBaseHelper` that will be like this

```
public ArrayList<User> getUsersList() {

        ArrayList<User> userList = null;
        Cursor cursor = null;

        try {

            String queryString = "SELECT _id , name, address, type FROM User";

            cursor =  myDataBase.rawQuery(queryString, null);

            if (cursor != null && cursor.moveToFirst()) {
                userList = new ArrayList<User>();
                do {
                    User nextUser = new User(cursor.getInt(0),
                            cursor.getString(1), cursor.getString(2) , cursor.getString(3));
                    userList.add(nextUser);
                } while (cursor.moveToNext());
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            userList = null;
        } finally {
            if (cursor != null && !cursor.isClosed()) {
                cursor.deactivate();
                cursor.close();
                cursor = null;
            }
            if(myDataBase != null){
                myDataBase.close();
            }
        }
        return userList;
    }
```

Comment: Yes thanks for the answer. But how to do it for the above example that i have given in the link ? Please help me for that. Where to write that query ?

Comment: I have told you to write this method in "DataBaseHelper" class. Just after checkDataBase() method.

Comment: Thanks it works for me. But i want to retrive only name from the database. And i want to set it in A,B,C,D from then how to do it ?

Comment: Then change the query "SELECT name, address, type FROM User" and you can get Name in iteration by "cursor.getString(0)".

Comment: Yes i got it as i want. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

[Here's](http://hackaday.com/2010/07/21/android-development-101-part-3introduction-to-databases/) brilliant tutorial about android data.The tutorial covers all the aspects of database.

Answer (score 1):

you can download one sample example from my computer. This is link. It will be available for today only. I am also giving you its code as below.

```
package com.collabera.labs.sai.db;

import java.util.ArrayList;

import android.app.ListActivity;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;

public class CRUDonDB extends ListActivity {

    private final String SAMPLE_DB_NAME = "myFriendsDb";
    private final String SAMPLE_TABLE_NAME = "friends";

    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);


        ArrayList<String> results = new ArrayList<String>();
        SQLiteDatabase sampleDB = null;

        try {
            sampleDB =  this.openOrCreateDatabase(SAMPLE_DB_NAME, MODE_PRIVATE, null);

            sampleDB.execSQL("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS " +
                    SAMPLE_TABLE_NAME +
                    " (LastName VARCHAR, FirstName VARCHAR," +
                    " Country VARCHAR, Age INT(3));");

            sampleDB.execSQL("INSERT INTO " +
                    SAMPLE_TABLE_NAME +
                    " Values ('Makam','Sai Geetha','India',25);");
            sampleDB.execSQL("INSERT INTO " +
                    SAMPLE_TABLE_NAME +
                    " Values ('Chittur','Raman','India',25);");
            sampleDB.execSQL("INSERT INTO " +
                    SAMPLE_TABLE_NAME +
                    " Values ('Solutions','Collabera','India',20);");

            Cursor c = sampleDB.rawQuery("SELECT FirstName, Age FROM " +
                    SAMPLE_TABLE_NAME +
                    " where Age > 10 LIMIT 5", null);

            if (c != null ) {
                if  (c.moveToFirst()) {
                    do {
                        String firstName = c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("FirstName"));
                        int age = c.getInt(c.getColumnIndex("Age"));
                        results.add("" + firstName + ",Age: " + age);
                    }while (c.moveToNext());
                } 
            }

            this.setListAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,results));

        } catch (SQLiteException se ) {
            Log.e(getClass().getSimpleName(), "Could not create or Open the database");
        } finally {
            if (sampleDB != null) 
                sampleDB.execSQL("DELETE FROM " + SAMPLE_TABLE_NAME);
                sampleDB.close();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks for the answer and help. But Arslan's answer help me as i want.

Comment: you welcome dear. Keep Sharing Knowledge , you can catch me live in my chat room http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/6137/